# How should "condolences" be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation, syllables

My word processor soft-hyphenated condolences as **condolenc-es**. Does this look natural to the eyes of native speakers? I, a non-native speaker, think it should be **condolen-ces**.

Comment: Knuth accepts only *con-do-lences* for purposes of hyphenation.  This is not the same as syllabification.

Comment: @tchrist That said, I wonder which rule that one is hitting... is it that it breaks condolences down as condolence + non-syllable-adding-s since most -e words + s don't add a syllable, or that it doesn't like three letters on the next line (but surely it splits din-ner, né?)?  I'm not one to question Knuth especially since it's pretty self-evident all the other options look...less than optimal, but still, curiousity and all.

Comment: @guifa I image it’s either not putting enough on the next line or it’s something about misleading hyphenation breaks making you pronounce the word wrong if you leave a “soft” *c* at the end. There may also be some morphemic-boundary thing going on, too.

Comment: con-do-lenc-es is how I'd split the syllables, but one should never hyphenate a word two characters from the end like that.

Comment: I think the syllables would be con-dol-enc-es according to James Hoard's theory in *Aspiration, Tenseness, and Syllabication in English*, http://www.jstor.org/stable/412191?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @sumelic: since the OP mentions his word processor soft-hyphating the word, it's about where hyphens can be placed to break the word between lines.

Answer (score 1):

con-do-lenc-es is how I'd split the syllables, but one should never (except in extreme situations) hyphenate a word two characters from the end like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you were going solely by pronunciation, you would split the word *condolen-ces*. The word is split *condolenc-es* to keep the root word *condolence* as intact as possible.

Looking at similar words, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chancellor) suggests the line-breaking hyphenations *chan-cel-lor* and *can-cel*, but *chanc-ing* and *danc-er*.

Answer (score -1):

The entire portion *lence* is a single syllable so it should technically not be split apart, however pluralizing the word causes the creation of an addistional syllable which cannot be expressed by *s* alone, so you'd have to add an extra *e* to express the proper syllable *es* so:

*con-do-lence-es*

from

**condolence**

```
  con·do·lence
```

Comment: As tchrist pointed out, hyphenation is not syllabification, so you would end up with *condolencees.

Comment: OK, you're right, I mistook the question. Why didn't Knuth answer in the form of an answer, though? Makes it awfully hard for the person asking to check their question off as having been answered if there isn't one.

Comment: Knuth is the author of the extremely good hyphenation algorithm (and program) used in TeX, and "Knuth says" is what you get when you use this to hyphenate "condolences".